# have bundler use http: instead of git:?

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I am installing [gitlabhq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq), and in the Gemfile there are references to 'git://...' for certain resources.

However, I am behind a corporate firewall, so I have to use http://.

I can hand-edit the Gemfile, but I was wondering if there was another way to tell bundler to use http:// for git repositories?

Comment: I don't think you can safely assume that there is an equivalent `http://` URL for every `git://` URL. Not all repositories support all protocols. Obviously for github-hosted repositories this isn't a problem.

Comment: @meagar - Even for github, it is only https

Comment: You may find that corkscrew allows you to sidestep this issue by proxying git connections over http. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corkscrew_(program)

Comment: Or https? I think your chances are good that HTTPS would work as well if all or most dependencies are hosted on GitHub? Would be nice to have a definitive answer on this question.

Comment: The HTTP and HTTPS protocols are definite second-class citizen for git. Apply a clue by 4 to the "network administrators"...

Answer (score 11):

You can configure git to use `https://` by running running `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` or by adding the following to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "https://"]
   insteadOf = git://
```